# handling null return from complex firebase database queries

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I have a search feature built into my app that filters users from my firebase database.

I am able to do this correctly to an extent. The issue is whenever I search for a user that doesn't exist the app crashes with the error: `Index out of range`

These are UICollectionViewCells so I handle the cells returned in `numberOfItemsInSection` and I thought I had coded for the condition nil or zero but apparently not.

Here is where the search is performed

```
func searchUsers(searchText: String) {

    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "name").queryStarting(atValue: searchText).queryEnding(atValue: "\(searchText)\u{f8ff}")
        .observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in

            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                let user = User()
                user.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)

                self.users.append(user)
                print(snapshot)

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                })
            }

                print(self.users.count)
        }, withCancel: nil)

}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: if your number of cell for sections return 0 your app should be fine, I think you never should return Int(), in any case return 0

Comment: You probably want `return users?.count ?? 0`

Comment: @Paulw11 Tried still getting error Index out of range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After carefully reading the documentation I was able to deduce the source of the error.
Here is a line from the FireBase documentation:

**"If no data exists at the specified location, the FDataSnapshot will return an NSNull."**

So to circumnavigate the error normally you would be able to add something along the lines of:

```
if snapshot.value == NSNULL {

    print("no users returned") 
} else {
//do something with data
```

However, with the FireBase query I was performing, the observation was that of .childAdded events.

The FireBase documentaion calls these queries, complex queriers. In my case I was using `.queryStarting` and  `.queryEnding` which only return .childAdded events so checking the value wouldn't work *inside* the query parameters and the application would crash.

The solution is to check if the query returns null ***BEFORE*** you preform the search.

This is especially important if you are using the data to return something like collectionView or tableView Cells.

So to wrap up, all I had to do, was simply add a reference observation on the query return value before I used it to create my UICollectionViewCells. That ended up looking like this.

```
ref.observe(.value, with: { snap in
    if snap.value is NSNull {
        print("no users returned")
        self.users.removeAll()

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        })

    }
})
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

you should not return Int() from the `numberOfItemsInSection` return 0 instead

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   switch section {
   case 0:
      return users.count
   case 1:
     // handle based on section 1 datasource count
}
```

Comment: There is another section. I didn't include it because the post was getting lengthy.

Comment: edited the answer, you should return 0 if the data is not there

Comment: Why so complicated? All of the code for `case 0:` can simply be: `return users.count`. No `guard` needed.

Comment: @rmaddy @suhit I still get bad instructions at `let user = users[indexPath.row]`

Comment: @Stefan share your `users` declaration code please .

Comment: @NazmulHasan `var users = [User?]()`... `User()` is an NSObject class

Comment: @Stefan it should be `var users = [User]()`

Comment: @NazmulHasan that's how I had it originally declared. I just tried it again. It doesn't work.

Comment: @Stefan if you trying this way `var users = [User]()` which line you getting error

Comment: @NazmulHasan   `let user = users[indexPath.row]`

Comment: @Stefan check the index exist or not
`let isIndexValid = users.indices.contains(indexPath.row)`